# How should I prove this vectors question?

Tags: vectors

$\textbf{Question:}$ $OAB$ is a triangle.

$Q$ is the point on $AB$ such that $OQP$ is a straight line, where $P$ is a point outside of the triangle.

$$\overrightarrow{OA}=4\bf{a},$$
$$\overrightarrow{OB}=6\bf{b},$$
$$\overrightarrow{AP}=2\bf{a}+\bf{8}b$$

Using a vector method, find the ratio, $AQ:QB$

$\textbf{Attempted solution:}$ I thought I had solved it, but then I realised I had made various assumptions, including the incorrect fact that $Q$ is the midpoint of $OP$. However, I think this much is correct: $$\overrightarrow{AQ}=-\bf{a}+4\bf{b}$$
$$\overrightarrow{QB}=-3\bf{a}-2\bf{b}$$
But I can't write these as factors of one another, so I've either made a mistake or there's something I'm not seeing. I also realised that I can't use Pythagoras' theorem because the vectors aren't necessarily orthogonal.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mw5Q.jpg)

Comment: You’ve made some mistake. Check whether $\vec{OA}+\vec{AQ} +\vec{QB}=\vec{OB}$

Comment: In situations like these, I often find it useful to turn the question into something a bit more familiar, solve that question, and then try to work backwards to get to the solution that I want. In this case, try drawing all of these as line segments on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and solve for the point of intersection between the line segment from $(0,6)$ to $(4,0)$ and the line segment from the origin to the point $(2,8)$. From there, it should only take a minute to find the ratios, and then you can try to find a way apply the vector methods that you know to get to that same answer

Comment: Is the answer 8:9? Just checking the answer to avoid posting a wrong answer.

Comment: I don't know what the answer is. That sounds plausible though. It's from an exam, and I doubt it's a really awful ratio. I'm trying to do as was suggested above, but I can't do so without making assumptions about the nature of the vectors (e.g. that they are perpendicular, which they definitely aren't in the diagram that comes with the paper).

Comment: I hope it isn't an ongoing exam :) just confirming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

All the lengths written in the image can be obtained via triangle law of vector addition by considering various triangles. (Left as an exercise for the reader )

 Let $\vec {AC}=\lambda\cdot \vec {AB}$  and $\vec {CB}=\mu \cdot \vec {AB}$. Now, $\vec {AC}+\vec{CB}=\vec{AB}$ so $\lambda + \mu =1$.

 Similarly, $\vec{OC}= \phi \vec {AP}$.

 Now, $$\vec{OA}+ \vec{AC}+ \vec{CO}= \vec{0}$$ so that $$4 \vec{a}+\lambda (6\vec{b}-4 \vec{a})+\phi (-8\vec{b}-6 \vec{a})= \vec{0}$$ or $$(4-4\lambda-6\phi) \vec{a}+(6\lambda-8\phi) \vec{b}= \vec{0}.$$

 Since $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are non collinear, so each of their coefficients is equal to 0; i.e.$$4-4\lambda-6\phi=0$$ and $$6\lambda-8\phi=0$$ from which $\lambda = \frac{8}{17}$. Obviously, $\mu=1-\lambda=\frac{9}{17}$ so that $$\frac{AQ}{QB}=\frac{\lambda|\vec{AB}|}{\mu |\vec{AB}|}=\frac{\lambda}{\mu}=\frac89.$$

Comment: Amazing! Many thanks. Not an ongoing exam, but a past paper I'm helping a friend prepare for, and we were both super stuck!

Comment: @Penguinking14 :)